# How to integrate $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

want to evaluate $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dxdydz$$ over entire $\mathbb{R}^3$ except $(0,0,0)$.

I did this using polar coordinate and got $$\lim\limits_{a\rightarrow0}\int\limits_a^\infty\int\limits_0^{\pi}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}r\sin\phi d\theta d\phi dr$$ but I think this diverges.

where am I wrong? help me please

Comment: Are you sure you wrote out your limit right? Specifically, I'm referring to your ordering of $d\theta$, $d\phi$, and $dr$

Comment: I think so. I used $x=rsin\phi cos\theta$, $y=rsin\phi sin\theta$, $z=rcos\phi$.

Comment: The integral is indeed infinite.

Comment: I think it's reasonable that this diverges.  If you consider the one-dimensional analogue of this it's $\lim_{a\to 0} \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$ which diverges, in both directions no less!

Comment: @Francesco, your spherical coordinate convention might just be different from the OP's.

Comment: rekt, did you remember to make the coordinate changes in your original integrand?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. it is in my last comment. I got $\theta$ on $xy$-plane, and got $\phi$ vertically.

Comment: @rekt, then your integrand times the Jacobian should only be $\sin\phi$, no?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. what? why? $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: Ah, right; the Jacobian is $r^2 \sin\phi$, so you cancelled everything correctly. The conclusion should now be clear.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be attempting is to set $r \rightarrow \infty$ and to calculate the volume of a sphere excluding the origin. This volume is indeed $\Bbb{R}^3-{\text{{(0,0,0)}}}$.

A more compact way of writing what you're attempting to find needs set notation, for instance.

Let $I = [0,\infty),r\in I$ and $A_r=\Bbb{\text{{(x,y,z)$\in$ $\Bbb{R}^3 |x^2+y^2+z^2>r^2$}}}$

The way to imagine this is that we're essentially creating every possible sphere and the volume is all the region outside those spheres. By integrating to infinity but excluding the origin you're taking the union of all possible spheres in $\Bbb{R}^3$ excluding the origin.

$\bigcup\limits_{r\in I} A_{r}$=$\Bbb{R}^3-{\text{{(0,0,0)}}}$

By taking the union of these sets we get the answer we expected. I would attempt to draw you a diagram for this problem but I hope this suffices.